# How to configure 'fetch' URL on user-triggered events with react native + redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need some advise or best practice on how to parameterize the prefix of the URL I need call when a user triggers an event, in a React Native + Redux environment.

Here is a dummyfied version of what I have so far:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import actions from "../actions/actions";
import MyWidget from "../components/MyWidget";

export const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        itemDetails: state.itemDetails
    };
};

const pushItem = (dispatch, itemDetails) => {
    fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/myapp/rest/item/" + itemDetails.id, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: itemDetails
    })
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(actions.hideSpinner());
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            dispatch(actions.hideSpinner());
        });
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        saveItem: itemDetails => {
            dispatch(actions.showSpinner());
            pushItem(dispatch, itemDetails);
        }
    };
};

const MyWidgetCtrl = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyWidget);

export default MyWidgetCtrl;
```

Here the saveItem function will be called when the user taps a button. This works fine, but my issue is that the http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/myapp part is hard-coded, and I want it to come from my application's settings instead. I was thinking of pulling the settings using AsyncStorage at startup and putting them in the Redux store, and then adapt the code above to get the URL prefix from the state; but the problem is that the mapDispatchToProps function does not receive the redux state as a parameter, so that won't work.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

EDIT: Note that I don't know the API url prefix in advance, so I can't put it in a config file at compile time. It's actually up to the user to type the API prefix in a prompt the first time he uses the app.

Comment: posted answer. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config) npm module to expose config variables to your javascript code in React Native, supporting both iOS and Android.

- You can create .env in the root of your React Native app.

  ```
   API_URL = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/myapp
  ```
- Then access variables defined there from your app.

  ```
   import Config from 'react-native-config'
   ...
   ...
   fetch(`Config.API_URL/itemDetails.id`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: itemDetails
   })
  ```

If the API prefix is taken as input from the user, then it can be maintained in the state/redux store and you can have a single http utility which can be the gateway for all the http calls for your app and where in you can access the props from the store.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is something else I should have mentioned: I don't know the API prefix in advance, so I can't put it in a config file at compile time. It's actually up to the user to type the API prefix in a prompt the first time he uses the app. Since react-native-config doesn't seem to support writes, it's not going to work...

Comment: @P.Oring, then you can maintain prefix in state. Updated the answer